# How to get camera settings from ImageCaptureCore

Tags: image, cocoa, image-capture

ImageCaptureCore does not provide an API to get camera settings, like White Balance, ISO etc., but it provides an API method `requestSendPTPCommand` from which is possible to get camera settings.

But the problem is no matter how I call this API, the `didSendPTPCommand` delegate method are always passed `NULL`.

1. Has anybody used `requestSendPTPCommand` before?
2. How to get camera settings in Cocoa?

Comment: Tried before but seems no way to get the camera settings.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since this question was asked but since I was looking into it myself and incase anyone else needs to know there is a useful example to the use of PTP commands in this old apple documentation [here](http://genekc07.stowers.org/Users/mec/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleLion.CoreReference.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/#samplecode/PTPPassThrough/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008916-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).